# WPF throwing warning on Dictionary Collection Changed in .Net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dictionary

I was using .Net 4.0 and had a `Dictionary` in my code like the one below

```
 public Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, ObservableCollection<Media>> FoldersDictionary
```

I am using this dictionary of to display the folders from windows directory in a surface list box. `DirectoryInfo` will contain the directory information about folders e.g their names and `Media` class will contain the data inside these folders.

When I add or remove items from the `ObservableCollection` in my `Dictionary`, WPF threw this warning at me:

```
Collection of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.IO.DirectoryInfo, 
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[Media, ViewModel, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' has been changed without raising
a CollectionChanged event.  Support for this is incomplete and inconsistent, 
and will be removed completely in a future version of WPF. Consider either (a) 
implementing INotifyCollectionChanged, or (b) avoiding changes to this type of 
collection`.
```

However I ignored this warning as my output was showing up alright. Yesterday I upgraded to .Net 4.5.1 on Windows 7 and ran this code. The warning was still the same but now every time I refresh my dictionary (meaning clearing it and then adding new stuff to `ObservableCollection`), the last `ObservableCollection` item is never visible on my UI. I debugged my code and found out that the `Dictionary` infact still has the last item added in it, its just that it is not being displayed on my WPF XAML UI. I wondered may be this behavior is due to the warning I see. I implemented the following `CollectionChanged` event to my code:

```
 private void OnUrlChanged(string newUrl)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUrl)) 
                return;

            var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(newUrl);
            DirectoryInfo[] directoryInfos = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

            if (directoryInfos.Any())
            {
                if (FoldersDictionary != null && FoldersDictionary.Any())
                {
                     FoldersDictionary.Clear();
                }

                FoldersDictionary = null;
                FoldersDictionary = new Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, ObservableCollection<Media>>();
                LoadFolders(FoldersDictionary, directoryInfos);
            }     
        }

 private void LoadFolders( Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, ObservableCollection<Media>> Folders, IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> directoryInfos)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo item in directoryInfos)
            {
                ObservableCollection<Media> medias = LoadMedias(item.FullName);

                //new code starts here
            medias.CollectionChanged+=new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(medias_CollectionChanged); 
                //new code ends here

                if (medias != null)
                {
                    Folders.Add(item, medias);
                }
            }
        }

//new code starts here
        void medias_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             //do nothing
        }

//new code ends here
```

My `Dictionary` `PropertyChanged` is given as:

```
        public const string FoldersDictionaryPropertyName = "FoldersDictionary";

        private Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, ObservableCollection<Media>> _foldersDictionary;

        public Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, ObservableCollection<Media>> FoldersDictionary
        {
            get { return _foldersDictionary; }

            set
            {
                if (_foldersDictionary == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, ObservableCollection<Media>> oldValue = _foldersDictionary;
                _foldersDictionary = value;



                RaisePropertyChanged(FoldersDictionaryPropertyName);


            }
        }
```

This is the XAML I am using.

```
<Grid Height="180">
                    <s:SurfaceListBox x:Name="xFoldersListBox"
                                      Background="{x:Null}"
                                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource                             SurfaceListBoxItemSquareStyle}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding FoldersDictionary}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FolderDataTemplate}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="Value"
                                      Template="{StaticResource SurfaceListBoxHorizontalTemplate}" />
 </Grid>


<DataTemplate x:Key="FolderDataTemplate">
            <s:SurfaceToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,
                                                       Mode=TwoWay,
                                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource   Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type s:SurfaceListBoxItem}}}" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key.Name}"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </s:SurfaceToggleButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

However I am still getting the same warning as before and further more I cant see my last folder in my dictionary being displayed at all when I clear and repopulate my `Dictionary`. Any idea what may be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is problematic when you recreate another instance of `FoldersDictionary`. If you just clear the Dictionary and re-populate it then the code works as expected, no warning either.

But I don't know WHY the last Directory is lost, I step into the code and found the key/value pairs are correct. Maybe Dictionary is not intended to be used like an ObservableCollection in data binding, as the warning suggests.

```
private void OnUrlChanged(string newUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newUrl))
        return;

    //instantiate only once
    if (FoldersDictionary == null)
    {
        FoldersDictionary = new Dictionary<DirectoryInfo,   ObservableCollection<Media>>();
    }
    else if (FoldersDictionary.Any())
    {
        FoldersDictionary.Clear();
    }

    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(newUrl);
    DirectoryInfo[] directoryInfos = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

    if (directoryInfos.Any())
    {                
        LoadFolders(FoldersDictionary, directoryInfos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will modify my code to this. You are right, its completely bizarre that the last element is lost in UI after "upgrading to .Net 4.5.1", as I could see all the elements in .Net 4.0. May be Microsoft did some changes in their framework, I cant figure out what they changed.

Answer (score 1):

As the warning suggested, `Dictionary` type doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. You need to create custom `Dictionary` that implement the interface to make it work.

Or you can try using `ObservableDictionary` from [this blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/). It is custom implementation of `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` interface, combined with `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces.

Comment: But then why was everything working in .Net 4.0 ? What has changed in .Net4.5.1 that is causing the last item of my Dictionary not appearing in the UI? Any idea about this?

Comment: You got (un)lucky with respect to timing or perhaps something else was triggering an update on your binding. Whatever it was, _it doesn't matter_. Your code was broken. Never create production code based on unintentional side effects if you can help it. Always work against the published interface. This is especially true in the Microsoft .net libraries like the BCL and WPF because the published interface is remarkably well documented.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding `FoldersDictionary` to the UI element. In order for WPF to string together everything, `FoldersDictionary` should raise `PropertyChanged` event. As the warning suggests, implement `INotifyPropertChanged` interface and attach the event handler to this property.

Comment: I have added the PropertyChanged in my code. See the edit in my original post

Comment: And it is not like I cant see any folder in my output UI. JUst the last item is always missing when using .net 4.5.1. In .net 4.0 there was no issue at all.